# Avro schema update optional field to required

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have an avro schema. It has a couple of fields. Among which is a field , which is presently optional ie, its type is ["null","string"]
Now , i want to make it non nullable, ie it shall not have null type.
Yet on making the change I get 409 Eror.
How can I make this change and not affect the avro schema backward compatibility check , or not make a breaking change

Comment: How would consumers read old messages in the topic that have null values?

Comment: seems then , i will have to make a breaking change and update consumer too!Thats what i want to understand, is that the only way out. #AvroRookie

Comment: depends on compatibility settings. you can remove the field and add it again as a mandatory.  provided your compatibility setting is not transitive: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html