# Debezium source connector database migrations breaking AVRO schema compatibility

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, avro, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

Sorry for the stupid title.

We're using Debezium source connector to stream changes from PostgreSQL to kafka. Along the way the connector is registering schemas to confluent schema-registry.

Streaming works like just fine but we have problems with schema evolution during certain database migrations done by our developers. By default the schema-registry has BACKWARD compatibility. The problem is you can't do certain migrations. For example you can't promote column to be `NOT NULL` in case it doesn't have default value set. This results in 409 from schema-registry.

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN username SET NOT NULL;
```

When I discovered it I thought maybe we can just create default value first and then set the `NOT NULL` constraint. But turns out it is also change that is not backward compatible:

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN username SET DEFAULT "default-username";
```

In other words it's not possible to promote AVRO optional field into required field. It's been discussed here: [Avro schema update optional field to required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957378/avro-schema-update-optional-field-to-required)

As workaround we've set `FORWARD` compatibility type. But it has the opposite problem. You can't delete mandatory field (drop not null column with no defaults). You can't turn the mandatory field into optional field (set default first).

I wonder what is the correct compatibility setting on schema-registry when it comes to source connector. It looks like we'll have to go with `NONE` compatibility in the end. I'm bit afraid it can cause troubles to our sink connectors and other consumers in the long run.

Comment: It all starts from DB. Since Avro schemas are derived from DB tables, there is no other way to have backwards compatible Avro schemas if the table schema is not backwards compatible.
Unless you educate developers to have backwards compatible migrations, there is no other way. This is one of the drawbacks of using CDC with schemas, IMO. Btw, in the company I work for, we also have `NONE` set as compatibility rule just because developers don't care about DB migrations being backwards compatible.

Comment: Thanks for insight. This is more or less I thought and we'll do same thing.

I think the main problem is that I can't say to developers 'never drop the not null column' or to 'never introduce not null constraint on column without default'. Columns come and go. Sometimes you need to change non mandatory one to mandatory or vice versa (drop it).

One way or another i'm going with `NONE` as I don't think in real world any other options is possible.